# Google OAuth 2.0 Login In MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

Im Trying to use the new Google OAuth 2.0 API In my Web Application Im getting Error in my application like 
 **Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined**

// Google Script:

```
<body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

      <div id="root"></div> 
</body>
```

// App Component

```
function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
console.log("Encoded JWT ID Token :" + response.credential);
var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
console.log(userObject);
setUser(userObject);

if (user !== null) {
  history.push("/profileSetup/P3");
}}


useEffect(() => {
/*global google*/
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id:
    "*****************************************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  callback: handleCallbackResponse,
});
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  document.getElementById("SignInDiv"),
  {
    theme: "outline",
    shape: "circle",
    width: "270",
    text: "signin_with",
    logo_alignment: "center",
  }
);
google.accounts.id.prompt();}, []);
```

//Error In the Console:

```
signin.js:36:1[enter image description here][1] Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at signin.js:36:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You called the gsi script to load on the render, but your linter and react doesn't know/don't see yet that this google object exists before the application loads that script. You can bypass this by just putting this on your component:
`declare var google: any;`